# Different IUserMapper implementation for different modules- NancyFx

Tags: .net, authentication, forms-authentication, nancy

I am currently working on a Nancy website which has two parts. One is for font end users and other is for admins. Both types of users have different login pages where `/login` only allows end users to login and `admin/login` allows only admins to login.

What I want to have is different implementations of `IUserMapper` interface. I want it to be resolved to `UserMapper` when `/login` is called and to `AdminMapper` when `/admin/login` route is called. `UserMapper` and `AdminMapper` classes are given below:

```
public class UserMapper: IUserMapper{
    //IUserMapper implementation
}
public class AdminMapper: IUserMapper{
//IUserMapper implementation
}
```

I have following code for forms auth in `RequestStartup` method

```
var formsAuthConfiguration = new FormsAuthenticationConfiguration()
                {
                    RedirectUrl = "~/login",
                    CryptographyConfiguration = CustomCryptographyConfiguration.Default,
                    UserMapper = container.Resolve<IUserMapper>()
                };

                FormsAuthentication.Enable(pipelines, formsAuthConfiguration);
```

How can I tell Nancy to map `IUserMapper` to `UserMapper` when `/login` is called and to `AdminMapper` when `/admin/login` is called.

Answer (score 0):

This has to be performed by yourself. There is no mechanic in Nancy that would be able to know how to handle this automatically

When you wire up your forms authentication and assign the `UserMapper` property, of the `FormsAuthenticationConfiguration` then you cannot resolve it from the container.

You are going to have to create the appropriate `IUserMapper` instance, per-request, based on the requested route. You can get the requested route from the `NancyContext` object that is passed into your `RequestStartup` method.